# Vertically center text with icon inside div-button

Tags: html, css

I am making some buttons for a project and am having an issue getting the text in the buttons to be vertically centered. I imagine i would just set a negative margin to the `<p>` element but its not working like I thought it would.

[image]

[**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/k9q0qhdj/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabscontainer1">
<div class="taskTabs">

<div class="taskTabs taskTab1"> <span class="taskIcons" id="taskIcon1"> </span> <p>Tasks</p> </div>
<div class="taskTabs taskTab2"> <span class="taskIcons" id="taskIcon2"> </span> <p>Completed Tasks</p> </div>
<div class="taskTabs taskTab3"> <span class="taskIcons" id="taskIcon3"> </span><p>Deleted Tasks</p> </div>

</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tabscontainer1{
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    left:0px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

.tabscontainer1:before{
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    left:0px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

.taskTabs{
    width:auto;
    height:66px;
    border-radius:8px;
    display:inline-block;
    left:0px;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top:17px;
    }

.taskTabs p{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size:17pt;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:16px;
    display:inline-block;
    }

.taskTab1{
     border: 1px solid #4c9cfd;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -o-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
    }

.taskTab2{
     border: 1px solid #4c9cfd;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -o-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
    }

.taskTab3{
     border: 1px solid #4c9cfd;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -o-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
    }

.taskIcons{
    background:url(images/TaskIconMap.png) no-repeat;
    width:40px;
    height:39px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:16px;
    margin-top:12px;
    }
#taskIcon1{
    background-position: 0px 0px;   
    }
#taskIcon2{
    background-position: -42px 0px; 
    }

#taskIcon3{
    background-position: -84px 0px;     
    }
```

[**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/k9q0qhdj/)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what is your desired output?

Comment: @claudios I updated the brief via your request. Thanks!

Comment: Answers are already displayed below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  vertical-align: middle; For 'P'tag and icon tag:

```css
.tabscontainer1{
 padding:0px;
 float:left;
 left:0px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
}

.tabscontainer1:before{
 padding:0px;
 float:left;
 left:0px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
}
 
.taskTabs{
 width:auto;
 height:66px;
 border-radius:8px;
 display:inline-block;
 left:0px;
 margin-right:15px;
 margin-top:17px;
 }

.taskTabs p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed",sans-serif;
  font-size: 17pt;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.taskTab1{
  border: 1px solid #4c9cfd;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -o-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
 }
 
.taskTab2{
  border: 1px solid #4c9cfd;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -o-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
 }
 
.taskTab3{
  border: 1px solid #4c9cfd;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -o-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
 }
 
.taskIcons{
 background:url(http://s32.postimg.org/9jx6xtvk5/Task_Icon_Map.png) no-repeat;
 width:40px;
 height:39px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:16px;
 margin-top:12px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }
#taskIcon1{
 background-position: 0px 0px; 
 }
#taskIcon2{
 background-position: -42px 0px; 
 }
 
#taskIcon3{
 background-position: -84px 0px;  
 }
```

```html
<div class="tabscontainer1">
<div class="taskTabs">

<div class="taskTabs taskTab1"> <span class="taskIcons" id="taskIcon1"> </span> <p>Tasks</p> </div>
<div class="taskTabs taskTab2"> <span class="taskIcons" id="taskIcon2"> </span> <p>Completed Tasks</p> </div>
<div class="taskTabs taskTab3"> <span class="taskIcons" id="taskIcon3"> </span><p>Deleted Tasks</p> </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for vertical align:

```css
.tabscontainer1{
 padding:0px;
 float:left;
 left:0px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
}

.tabscontainer1:before{
 padding:0px;
 float:left;
 left:0px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
}
 
.taskTabs{
 width:auto;
 height:66px;
 border-radius:8px;
 display:inline-block;
 left:0px;
 margin-right:15px;
 margin-top:17px;
 }

.taskTabs p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed",sans-serif;
  font-size: 17pt;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.taskTab1{
  border: 1px solid #4c9cfd;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -o-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
 }
 
.taskTab2{
  border: 1px solid #4c9cfd;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -o-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
 }
 
.taskTab3{
  border: 1px solid #4c9cfd;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  -o-box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #01101f;
 }
 
.taskIcons{
 background:url(http://s32.postimg.org/9jx6xtvk5/Task_Icon_Map.png) no-repeat;
 width:40px;
 height:39px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:16px;
 margin-top:12px;
 }
#taskIcon1{
 background-position: 0px 0px; 
 }
#taskIcon2{
 background-position: -42px 0px; 
 }
 
#taskIcon3{
 background-position: -84px 0px;  
 }
```

```html
<div class="tabscontainer1">
<div class="taskTabs">

<div class="taskTabs taskTab1"> <span class="taskIcons" id="taskIcon1"> </span> <p>Tasks</p> </div>
<div class="taskTabs taskTab2"> <span class="taskIcons" id="taskIcon2"> </span> <p>Completed Tasks</p> </div>
<div class="taskTabs taskTab3"> <span class="taskIcons" id="taskIcon3"> </span><p>Deleted Tasks</p> </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Still have 4 min left before I can award answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just added the following to `.taskTabs p{}`

```
margin: 0; /* for good measure */
vertical-align: 9pt; /* roughly half the font-size */
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k9q0qhdj/3/